# Can AlarmManager schedule more than one alarm from the same code?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

If I allow my user to schedule a notification using AlarmManager, and then they schedule another notification using the same code, will the first alarm be overridden? Or will both alarms be set?

Answer (score 1):

When creating a pendingIntent you have to include an id:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ID , intent, Flags)
```

If the number in the ID location is always the same, then the alarm will be overridden. If it is the same then it will not be.

You can use the same code, as long as the ID is different. You can achieve this in many ways, like creating an ID based on the time you schedule the alarm for, as you may not need two alarms for the same time.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out tomorrow

Comment: So I'm incrementing a counter every time the method is called, and passing that as the second  parameter for the pendingIntent. Still only shows me the last alarm created.